# internal error: failed to deserialize keys buffer"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows, error-log, keys-file

There was already a similar topic, but I have a different problem with this error:

I used Monero wallet on Windows and had no problems.

Turned off the computer, walked away, came back and gives this error. I didn't make any changes to the files. Didn't update wallet.
Used VPN while working with Monero wallet. Without tor and i2p.

I don't have a 25 word phrase. There are no required keys. There is only a password and the .keys file itself

I reinstalled the client, tried to run my wallet file on another windows. Nothing helped. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Can you remove the wallet cache (the file without extension) and simply try to open the `.keys` file?

Comment: How can I do that? I would be grateful for instructions.

Comment: @Mr.Skifint - Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero\<wallet-name>` on Windows | `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` on Linux | `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` Mac OS X). Subsequently, rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`

Comment: @dEBRUYNE I made the prefix -old, but it did not change the situation. The error is the same. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1MJB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1MJB.png) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJaLe.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJaLe.png)

Comment: Did you set up the wallet with a Ledger or Trezor device?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE No, I don't have either of those. To recover a wallet on Ledger or Trezor, you need to enter a seed phrase, but I don’t have it.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. In case it is a standard 'wallet', I think the `.keys` file somehow got corrupted. Which operating system do you use?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE I used windows 10 OS on virtual box. I tried to do a system restore, but there are no restore points.

Comment: @Mr.Skifint - Apologies for the late response. You, by any chance, don't have a backup of the `.keys` file?

Comment: Any solutions to this i am currently going through the same issue?